# Java TimerTask won't out put text in selenium

Tags: java, servlets, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a selenium script using remote webdriver. I am using `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()` to ouput my data but when I use `PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();` to output `writer.prntln("Testing Started");` it does not show on webpage when it is inside the Timer. But it works outside the Timer. Also if I do `system.out.println` inside the timer it works.

```
protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    int delay = 1000;
    int period = 1000;
    Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
        {

            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            int count = 0;
            public void run()
            {

                              //WebDriver actions in here.


                }
           }, delay, period);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that `Timer` spawns a new thread, so the code inside the `run()` method is executed asynchronously. By the time it gets executed, your `doGet()` method might well have completed and the response been flushed.

Creating news thread inside a servlet method is usually a bad idea. If you really want to do asynchronous processing, you might want to take a look at the asynchronous servlets in the Servlet 3.0 spec.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but there might be an easier way to do that than using a `Timer` object. If you just want to delay the execution of the current thread inside a loop, you can use `Thread.sleep()` instead.

Comment: Its not the delay I want, its the output. Basically, when selenium does a click, I want it to output text like "Clicked on Search" before going to the next step. When I use sleep, it completes the entire process then outputs all the text at the same time. How can I pause the entire script, output text, then resume?

Comment: Try calling `response.flushBuffer()` before calling `sleep()`.